# Is it necessary to have Maven and Junit or TestNG to run sauce labs for mobile testing

Tags: maven, selenium, appium, saucelabs

We have a custom framework built for Selenium with Java and we do not use Junit or TestNG and Maven. We are using to ant build our project. So I wanted to understand is it necessary to have Maven and Junit or TestNG to run sauce labs for mobile testing? We are planning to include Appium in our framework and would like explore way for executing our test on sauce lab.

If there are any alternate option we have then please point me to them.

Thanks,

Raghav

Answer (score 0):

So, since you are using Ant, then the answer is `No` you do not need maven.  Both Ant and Maven are project dependency management tools.

As far as the testing framework goes, you don't *have* to use any of them, but the reason you would want to use them, is for Pass/Fail recognition.

With a testing framework you can run each test individually and see a green pass, or red fail within your IDE. As well as suite management (See [TestMethodRunner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/textui/TestRunner.html)) It's possible that SauceLabs can detect these frameworks and detect failures as well, so I wouldn't see why you wouldn't use at least jUnit or TestNG.